# panel not displayed sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a 'vbox' panel as below,

```
 {xtype:'panel',
    id:'srchResPanel',
    layout:'vbox',
    scrollable:false,

    items:[
     {
       xtype:'toolbar',
       docked:'top',
       height:46,
       style:'border-top-left-radius:10px;',
       title:'some title'
         }

    ]}
```

I am trying to add 2 panels dynamically to the above panel, they are as below

```
var header  =  Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
         height:40,
         width:'100%',

    scrollable: {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        directionLock: true
    },

         layout:'hbox',
     });

    header.setHtml('<div style="font-size:15px;>header</div>');
```

and

```
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
         width:'100%',

    scrollable: {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        directionLock: true
    },
         layout:'vbox',

     });
Ext.getCmp('srchResPanel').add(header);
Ext.getCmp('srchResPanel').add(grid);
```

when i add the above 2 panels to the top panel, only the first panel(header) is displayed
the second panel(grid) is not getting displayed.

any help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `height` for your second panel as well.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. But why the panel didnt display when no height was provided. ?

Comment: It's just like normal css, if you don't set any height and width for a div, the default height and width for that div will be `0px `